# What does "rewire your brain" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read the sentence:

> You need to ***rewire your brain.***

I cannot find the meaning of 'rewire your brain' in dictionaries. Is it an idiom?

Comment: Useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67639/whats-the-meaning-of-wired/67640#67640

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiom or not, it's quite straightforward once you know what it means.
In other words, this could be a cultural thing.

From an article on [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/everybody-is-stupid-except-you/201112/it-rewires-your-brain-think-again):

> What does it mean to rewire your brain? In one sense, it's trivial: it means that connections between neurons in your brain are changing. Everything we learn is stored in the brain, and the brain can't store information if it doesn't physically change in some (usually routine) way. In this sense, your brain is constantly being rewired, even right now.

That quote should answer your question about the meaning. As to whether *rewire your brain* is an idiom or not, I'll [take the fifth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_fifth). ;-)